# Why does \setdefaultlanguage modify my fontfamily?

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia

Please see this example code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

`test` is written in `\rmfamily` not `\sffamily`.
But when you kill the third line with `\setdefaultlanguage` the correct font is used.

Why? What is behind that?

Comment: I don't have a good "why", but I have a good workaround. Replace your `\renewcommand*` with `\newfontfamily\germanfont{Arial}` or whatever other font you want. See section 4 of the [`polyglossia`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) documentation.

Comment: The language file sets `fontsetup=true` which triggers Polyglossia's automatic font configuration.

Comment: @MikeRenfro That's not a good workaround. All kinds of things rely on `\normalfont` and this will break all of them.

Comment: If you want to set the default font for the document you really need `\setmainfont` or similar.

Comment: @cfr Can I loosely define "good" as "fixes the symptom for this MWE", and plead ignorance beyond that?

Comment: @MikeRenfro Sure. If that's how you define 'good' then, yes, it is a good workaround. [It is just not a good* workaround where 'good*' refers to a more usual sense of 'good' ;).]

Comment: (Expanding slightly on cfr's comment.) you are trying to use 'standard' (pdf)latex font commands in a xelatex document. Usually, if you're going to use polyglossia, you also want to use fontspec.

Comment: @jon but the document is still using the LaTeX2e format... hence the LaTeX2e commands should work as expected...

Comment: @jfbu -- a fair point, certainly (and +1). However, the OP may not realize that XeTeX (even in the LaTeX format) works differently under the hood and that there is a specialized font package designed for the xelatex and lualatex formats.

Comment: @jon agreed and perhaps one only needs to mention explicitly here that `polyglossia` does load `fontspec` ? ;-) thus, yes, using `fontspec`'s commands definitely makes sense. (in some contexts one needs `\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}` before loading `polyglossia`)

Comment: @jfbu -- absolutely!

Answer (score 9):

This is arguably a bug in polyglossia. Examining the `polyglossia.sty` one sees it has a concept of `\familytype`. When the user has selected a language, the font selection is influenced by it this tests the value of `\familytype`.

There is some code to set during package loading `\familytype`:

```
\expandafter\ifx\familydefault\sfdefault
  \def\familytype{sf}
\else\expandafter\ifx\familydefault\ttdefault
  \def\familytype{tt}
\else
  \def\familytype{rm}
\fi\fi
```

This has two issues:

1. arguably it should be done at begin document, not during package loading, to allow user's redefinitions of `\familydefault` anywhere in the preamble (and personally I would wish to also be able to define it in the document body, it is not immediately clear to me why `polyglossia` needs its own `\familytype` rather than `\familydefault`, restricting the efficiency of the latter).
2. the `\expandafter\ifx\familydefault` constrains user's definition of `\familydefault` to be done in a certain way, actually it constrains it to be in the style of the OP: `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}`. In particular `\let\familydefault\sfdefault` would lead to unexpected outcome. But ideally the full expansion should be used.

Thus there are two work-arounds: first one is to do `\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}` **before** loading `polyglossia`, alternative is to do `\def\familytype{sf}` at the end of the preamble.

First method:

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\def\test{test}
%\def\familytype{sf}
% \tracingmacros1
\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

Second method:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\def\test{test}
\def\familytype{sf}
% \tracingmacros1
\begin{document}
\test
\end{document}
% Local Variables:
% TeX-engine: xetex
% End:
```

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: [Bug Report](https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/127)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `\AtBeginDocument{\normalfont}` in the preamble anywhere after `\setdefaultlanguage` will also suffice as a workaround

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\AtBeginDocument{\normalfont}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```